# Did annual Sharpe ratio follows T distribution?

Tags: statistics, sharpe-ratio

Under some special condition, Sharpe ratio can be annualized by multiply $\sqrt{252}$, Since daily Sharpe ratio ($\frac{mean(r)}{std(r)}*\sqrt{T}$) follows student T distribution with degree of freedom T-1, then what about annual Sharpe ratio? I thought it should follows student T as well with degree of freedom $\frac{T}{\sqrt{252}} -1$ since: $$\text{annual SR}=\frac{mean(r)}{std(r)}*\sqrt{252}$$
so:$$\frac{mean(r)}{std(r)}*\sqrt{T} = \text{annual SR}*\frac{\sqrt{T}}{\sqrt{252}}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Hi: See this link. I think that it willl answer your question. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60586/t-statistics-on-monthly-returns-vs-annualized-monthly-returns/60613#60613